# How can I manually install the php slim?

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

Since I'm in China, it's hard for me to use composer to install the php slim. Thus, I'd like to install it manually. When I look up the guidance, it says that I should download the zip file of slim from Github and add the code:

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
```

However, There is no Slim.php in the zip file which is downloaded from:
https://github.com/slimphp/Slim

Could anyone tell me which file I should require now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the current repo, it looks like the Slim.php code was moved over to App.php.

Try this instead:

```
require 'Slim/App.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the Slim framework from here the link below. They take care of the Composer bits for you. https://php-download.com/package/slim/slim

Comment: This appears to require a paid subscription.